# WPF Binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection(Of MyClass)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, listbox

I have a Public Property StaticFailingPinListItem  As New ObservableCollection(Of MyClass) in my main user control, UserControl1.

```
Public Class UserControl1
  Public Property StaticFailingPinListItem As New ObservableCollection(Of MyClass)
```

MyClass has two properties - PinName & ImageLocation.

```
Public Class MyClass
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
  Public Property PinName
  Public Property ImageLocation
```

If I manually add items to the collection at runtime, I would be able to view PinName property in my listbox. However, it doesn't work if I were to add items at a later time (eg: after a button is clicked).

This is my xaml:

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName =data2, Path=StaticFailingPinListItem}" DisplayMemberPath="PinName"
```

So, the question is how I do a code-behind databinding for my listbox after the collection is populated?

Answer (score 0):

Interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` must be implemented by a class which contain a bonded property.
In your case this must be `UserControl1`

You need to implement this interface on the `UserControl1` type

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Public Property StaticFailingPinListItem As New ObservableCollection(Of MyClass)
```

When you add items after button is clicked, then control will be notified about changes in collection